# C# STAThreads not being cleaned up - OutOfMemory exception

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, garbage-collection, sta

I have a console application which takes as input a folder, picks up all the files in that folder and process them.
The processing is sequentially and for each document it launches a separate STAThread that runs a WPF dependent action inside it.

The application manages to process ~1k documents before getting an OutOfMemoryException and throwing an error because the Dispatcher is null.

Looking with ProcessExplorer I can see that:

- there aren't any running/hanging .NET threads
- there are ~49k handles allocated when it crashes
- out of these 4k are Thread handles

**Questions:**

1. What could cause the thread handles to not be released (I can see them being created and deleted live in ProcExplorer but it doesn't seem to keep up with the rate they're being created).
2. How could I see what are those 49k handles ? ProcessExplorer only shows about 5k items - what are the rest of them?
3. How can I workaround the OutOfMemory exception? My understanding is the entire process dies because it ends up allocating too much memory and causing fragmentation. I tried separating the threads via AppDomains + calling GC forcefully but nothing changed.

Comment: I cannot see your code so it is tough to say. Are you following the best practices of disposing of objects once you do not need them? Perhaps you can post some of your code

Comment: a wild guess is all folder paths (count=N) are read in one thread (a very quick one) and the process for each one (long process) starts in another thread. i.e. 1 + N threads. these N long threads cannot possibly start all at the same time because of resource limits.

Comment: If you realy do create 4k, you should fix that by switching to the TPL, more threads does not eventually always faster

Comment: Please provide us with a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

It's been a while but I'd like to capture the answer just in case someone runs into this issue as well.

The problem was caused by double shutdown of the WPF.

Because of how we were calling Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown, sometimes it resulted in multiple calls on the same in the same thread which even though doesn't result in any exceptions, every subsequent call to WPF will no longer dispose the handles and will result in a memory leak